# Limiting, scaling and biasing analog input (ADC) of microcontroller

Tags: sensor, adc, analog

I have [current transformer](http://www.elecfreaks.com/store/sensors-power-measurement-c-15_18.html) coils to monitor a gas-powered AC generator output (A & B) and 4 load circuits.

The output of the T1 coil with a 1500 watt load is about 30Vpp.

Will this circuit properly scale the input to the AD converter?
Are these good values for the resistors?  (revised 12/24/12 to use 1k+100 )
How can I protect the AD input from exceeding 5V?

```
AD-GND      A         1k
-----,--@--------\/\/\/---------------------Ax-+
     |  T1                            100      |
     +------------------------------\/\/\/--Ay-+------- AD-input1
     |
     |       B        1k
     +--@---------\/\/\/--------------------Bx-+
     |  T2                            100      |
     +------------------------------\/\/\/--By-+------- AD-input2
     |
     ...
     | 
     +--@-----  as above
        T4
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to build a 10:1 voltage divider. I would wonder: is it okay for ADC to share ground with these large power coils? Using a differential ADC input over a current-sensing resistor in series with the coil circuit would isolate the microcontroller's ground.

Comment: Are you planning to compute RMS current, peak current, or just a general indication of the current through your load?  In addition to your scaling circuit (voltage divider) and protection circuit (try a zener), you'll probably want a full bridge rectifier in front of each coil to aid compatibility with your unipolar ADC input.

Comment: @HikeOnPast - Rectifying AC for measurement is a lot harder then that. The diodes will cause a non-linearity, and incorrect readings at low voltages. Look into true-RMS converters for properly getting the AC rms value.

Comment: @FakeName, great point.  I missed that.

Answer (score 5):

When used properly, a current transformer produces an output current that is proportional to its input current by some fixed ratio. You convert this current to a voltage for measurement by allowing it to flow through a load resistor, and the voltage/current scale factor is directly controlled by the value of the load resistor that you use.

For example, some of the transformers you have linked to have ratios of 1000:1 or 2000:1. Let's pick a 1000:1 transformer: If you apply 10A<sub>rms</sub> to its input, it will generate a current of 10mA<sub>rms</sub> at its output. If you want this to scale to fit within an ADC range of, say, 0-5V, you would use a load resistor of 100Ω to turn this into a voltage waveform of 1.00V<sub>rms</sub> (2.828V<sub>p-p</sub>).

You would need to bias one end of the coil/load resistor combination to +2.5V in order to keep the other end, which will swing from 1.086V to 3.914V, within the range of the ADC. See the example on [Circuitlab](https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/5e9d73/current-transformer-interface/):

[image: schematic diagram]

Your proposed circuit is loading the current transformer with a total of 11K, which is far too high. In this mode of operation, the output of the transformer is no longer directly proportional to load current.

Comment: Dave, Thanks again for your information. Can you provide any advice regarding providing limit protection for the ADC port.

Comment: Well, now that you've got the "normal" signal well away from the supply rails, the most direct approach would be to use a pair Schottky diodes from the input to each supply rail. The impedance of the 2.5V bias source can serve to limit the fault current through those diodes.

Comment: Could you please provide some specifics regarding the location and orientation of the Schottkys?

Comment: I've added a diagram to the answer.